# Qual função javascript uso para extrair um bloco HTML de um lugar e inseri-lo em outro na mesma pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Seguinte estou mexendo no `moodle` e 90% do html dele é gerado via backend, preciso mudar um `<h1 id='courseheader')>Title</h1>` de lugar via javascript ja que não tenho acesso a esse elemento, a ideia era retirá-lo de onde está para jogá-lo dentro de um container que tenho na mesma pagina.

Qual função javascript/JQuery posso usar para isso?

Procurei no google mas não consegui expressar a dúvida de uma forma tão clara que pudesse me retornar respostas.

Espero que aqui esteja claro a dúvida, qualquer coisa edito. Obrigado.

Exemplo:

```html
<h1 id='courseheader')>Title</h1>

<div class="container"> Quero retirar o h1 ali de cima e colocá-lo aqui dentro</div>
```

Obs.: Eu até poderia criar um h1 novo dentro do container via JS mas gostaria de aproveitar o que já tem.

**Obs2.:**  Esqueci de mencionar, que eu quero que esse `h1`se junto aos outros elementos dentro do container e que ele se mantenha dentro da tag `h1`...

Comment: Um pouco pedante mas é interessante notar que o que você quer é mudar de lugar um _elemento DOM_ .

Comment: você quer uma solução usando jquery ou vanilla JS?

Comment: Na vdd gostaria de saber a função, usando jquery.   Acho até uma pergunta meio 'besta'  mas so precisava saber qual função usar ... @CaioFelipePereira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo como exemplo, ele:

1. Captura o elemento `h1` desejado através do `ID`
2. Captura o elemento `container` através do `className`
3. Adiciona ao `textContent` do container um novo elemento clone de `h1` através do método `cloneNode(true)`

**Nota**: Para que não houvesse quebra de linha no container, foi necessário adicionar a propriedade `display: inline;`

```js
//Recuperando elemento H1 
var h1Element = document.getElementById("courseheader");

//Recuperando elemento container
var containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

//Adicionando conteúdo do h1 ao container
containerElement.appendChild(h1Element.cloneNode(true));
```

```css
h1{
  display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<h1 id='courseheader'>Title</h1>

<div class="container"> Quero retirar o h1 ali de cima e colocá-lo aqui dentro</div>
```

Comment: Dei uma editada na minha pergunta acho que esqueci de mencionar que preciso que o h1 se mantenha dentro do container e que não apague os demais elementos que lá existe e sim se junte a eles.

Comment: @Erick Resposta atualizada

Comment: +1 por usar JS puro

Comment: Legal to mexendo aqui para colocar ele no topo =D ... Mas obrigado aos dois que ajudaram, era isso ai que eu queria mesmo... vlwww

Comment: A ultima linha do codigo coloquei  containerElement.insertBefore(h1Element.cloneNode(true) , containerElement.firstChild);  e o elemento ficou em primeiro lugar =D

Answer (score 1):

Usando `jQuery`, você tem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Não sei se é a mais performática ou a mais elegante, mas resolve o problema. Veja:

```js
var _h1 = $('#courseheader').html();

var _container = $('.container');

setTimeout(function(){
  _container.append(' ' + _h1);  
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id='courseheader'>Title</h1>

<div class="container"> Quero retirar o h1 ali de cima e colocá-lo aqui dentro</div>
```

O `setTimeout` é uma perfumaria, apenas pra você ver funcionando.

**EDIT**

Eu propositalmente apaguei o conteúdo da `div` porque achei que era isso que você queria. Editei o código pra ficar de acordo com o seu comentário

Comment: Legal, e mais ou menos isso ai que eu quero, na vdd ele não poderia apagar o conteúdo que esta dentro da div e sim apenas se juntar aos outros elementos, mas vc ja deu o caminho, vou mexer no código para ver se consigo resolver ... Obrigado Caio.

Comment: Veja a resposta editada

Comment: Cara so uma duvida besta,  o que vc mudou no codigo mesmo para não apagar o conteudo que estava na div container?

Comment: Mudei de `_container.html('').append(_h1);` para `_container.append(' ' + _h1);`

Comment: haha vlw onbrigado